# Does Creating DeleteBucket policy affect Deleting thru AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I created this delete policy, which denies deletes to everyone. Does this means I can't delete the bucket through the AWS Console when I log in with the admin username/password?

```
{
      "Id": "ExamplePolicyId12345678",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "ExampleStmtSid12345678",
          "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteBucket"
          ],
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-example-com",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "*"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the bucket from AWS console. You will get **Access Denied** error message. To delete the bucket, you need to delete/remove the bucket policy, save and try deleting.